# Can't build a PDF File

Tags: pdftex

I use Texmaker and Miktex (I can't switch to other programs because they were given to me by the university) and everything has worked until now.
But I have now changed the file name of a document afterwards and no more PDFs are created. However, no error message is output either.
I tried to change the file name back to the original one, restarted the computer, checked the configuration, also reinstalled both programs and tried again and again with simple attempts whether it worked again (I tried to write a sentence and display it in the PDF , because you can't really do anything wrong with the code)
Nothing helped.
Does anyone know this problem and can please help me?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[german]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb}

\author{Lisa}

\begin{document}
    Hello 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you post your code, or part of it, see what's going wrong?

Comment: Try to compile on a terminal/command line.

Comment: \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{Lisa}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}

Comment: Thats my current code, I am sorry for the formation, I am new on StackExchange and i don't know how to share a code properly

Comment: Just add 4 spaces before any \ command you want to show as code. What is the problem? this compiles for me using MikTex.

Comment: Since you used the word `pdftex` as a tag could it be that you are using `pdftex` rather than `pdflatex` ti typeset your file? You don't include any information about typesetting errors, etc., so we can't tell what is happening at your end.

Comment: Before I changed the file name, the compilation worked for me too, but since I changed the name, TexMaker won't create any PDFs, even if I create a new document.

Comment: No I am using pdflatex, I am sorry for the missunderstanding. Like I have already said, I haven't got any error messages, so I can't share them.

Comment: miktex has its own editor, texworks. Try to compile there. Unrelated but remove `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} \usepackage{ucs}`. ucs is seldom needed in a document.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works with texworks, but unfortunatelly I am not allowed to use this editior, my homework has to be written on texmaker.

Comment: how should anyone know which one you used?

Comment: the file is the same if you write it in texworks or texmaker or notepad, they are just the editor and have no effect on pdflatex processing the file to make pdf output

Comment: As much, your work has to be written in a plain text with LaTeX markup, and exported to PDF file with some LaTeX engine, but, for sure, the editor to used to type the text and run the engine is only a suggestion, since it is completely irrelevant, as David said. Moreover, noboby  can trace what editor you used from the .tex or .pdf files. Thus, if you do not have the rector watching you behind your back to prevent you from use another editor, feel free to use texworks, gummi, visual code, or whatever.